# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

Tags: spring-boot, controller, http-status-code-404, resttemplate

I have RestTemplate like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        internetMessageId = null;
        projectId = null;
        EmailJSON emailJSON = null;
        String path = urlProps.getRegionalUsUrl() + Constants.Url.Email.EMAIL_FIND_EMAIL_BY_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_AND_PROJECT_ID
+ "/" + internetMessageId + "/";
        if(projectId != null) {
            path += "?projectId=" + projectId;
        }
        ResponseEntity<EmailJSON> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, EmailJSON.class);
        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            emailJSON = responseEntity.getBody();
        }

        return  emailJSON;
```

and hits controller which looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getEmailByInternetMessageIdAndProjectId/{internetMessageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody EmailJSON getEmailByInternetMessageId(@PathVariable("internetMessageId") String internetMessageId, @RequestParam(value = "projectId", required = false) String projectId) {

        return emailService.getEmailByInternetMessageIdAndProjectId(internetMessageId, projectId);
```

and it works in some cases, but for some I'm getting

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
    2         at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.3.6      .RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    1         at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEA      SE]
37664         at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    1         at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    2         at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    3         at com.copperdm.global.web.service.utils.SharedServicesUtils.findEmailByInternetMessageIdAndProjectId(SharedServicesUtils.java:98
```

I tried to see what will happen if I set both parameter as null, but it was working fine. What could cause this error?

Comment: can you share on which case it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I found why it didn't work, I was getting an empty string as internetMessageId, so I added

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestBody.set("internetMessageId", internetMessageId);
        requestBody.set("projectId", projectId);
```

and changed controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getEmailByInternetMessageIdAndProjectId", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody EmailJSON getEmailByInternetMessageId(@RequestBody String internetMessageId,@RequestBody String projectId)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Note: My application implemented concept of `service registry` and `context path`.
I was getting the same error...
It was `context path` related issue for my application.
I was calling one microservice from another, but was not adding context path to microservice endpoint.
.